# How do I set the default c# file in my Visual Studio Code c# Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0

I am new to using Visual Studio Code. I have always used Visual Studio IDE in Windows. I am trying to run a simple Hello World Program on Mac with VS Code. I ran the following command

> dotnet new console

which successfully created the csProj file and Program.cs file with the code `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");` Now by issuing dotnet run command I can get the output from this Program as well.
But I have a different cs file called "**Hello.cs**" in the same Project location. How do I get the **Hello.cs** to run instead of the default "**Program.cs**" created by `dotnet new console` command.
I tried giving the following property group in the .csproj file but VS Code reports error this is reserved property.

```
<PropertyGroup><StartupObject>Hello.HelloWorld</StartupObject></PropertyGroup>
```

Is there another way to choose your default startup CS File if you have multiple CS files in your Project.

Comment: Just call into whatever class you have inside Hello.cs from Program.cs

Comment: In C# files are irrelevant; classes are important. You asking "how do I get hello.cs to run" is slightly the wrong thing to ask; code that runs lives inside classes, and any number of classes may be present inside a single .cs file.  We typically make a file per class but we don't have to, so try to avoid seeing the files as having any importance or relevance to the structure of the code at all

Comment: @CaiusJard that is not more true since C# 9 Top-level statements ;-)

Comment: I disagree; only one file may have top level statements and a TLS file may also have other classes and namespaces in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> dotnet new console
> command creates a new C# Console Project based on **C# 10.0** . This creates a Program.cs file that has something called as a ***Top Level Statement without a main method.*** as shown below:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Notice that this does not have the default Main() method which is usually the starting entry point for CS Console Application Projects
Once this statement is introduced in a .cs file in my csProject any other cs file I create and declare my classic entry point defined by my **Main()** method *will be ignored for the purpose of Entrypoint*. <<== This is a very important point to understand.

My Hello.cs file had the following code:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World1");
    }
```

This was ignored by C# 10.0 compiler. [From C# 9.0 onwards this is the behavior].
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements

Now All I had to do to make my Hello.CS Main() method my entry point to my C# Console Project is to get rid of the default top level entry point automatically created by the `dotnet new console` command.

Now I commented out this line in my Program.cs file

```
//Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Rerun my Project `[Command+Shift+D]` and voila! I have my code in Hello.cs now executing.

Answer (score 0):

The entry point of your application will be the method called `Main()` in the default namespace of your project. If you want to change the entry point, you can rename your methods, but a better way would be to simply call the code you want to run from **"Hello.cs"** in your `Main()` method in **"Program.cs."**

Comment: I get the feeling the confusion will be coming because the OP's project doesn't contain an obvious Main() method (top level statements)

Answer (score 0):

With using C# 9 Top-level statement feature you can have only one entry point. so you dont need select a default entry point. Remove all Main methods from other files and other top-level files if you want to use this feature.

[Read more about Top-level statements...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements)

Comment: Do you mean to assert that before TLS you could have multiple entry points?

Comment: LOL Yes and No. You can only have one entry point, but you can have more as one Main method. One of them is the entry point. That's why you have to select an entry point if more than one main method exists.

Comment: Thanks @kux for pointing me in the right direction, I have solved my issue and posted how I did it as my Answer :-)